# input and sum the numbers - java

Tags: java, file-io

```
    import java.util.Scanner; //Needed for the scanner class
    import java.io.File; //Needed for the file class
    import java.io.IOException; //Needed for the IOException

    public class AverageGrade {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            int i = 0;
            double sum = 0.0;
            double gradeTotal =  0.0;

            // Open the file

            File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\life__000\\Desktop\\Eclipse - Java\\AverageGrade\\src\\myGrades.txt");
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myFile);

            //Read lines from the file until no more are left.
            while (myScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                //Read the next name
                gradeTotal = myScanner.nextDouble();

                i++;

                //Display the last name read.
                System.out.println(gradeTotal);
            }

            // Close the file.
            myScanner.close();
        }
```

This is my code. It reads the file input but it doesn't add them up. I want to add the numbers and then take the average of them. I already tried 
`gradeTotal += myScanner.nextDouble();`
but using the above line prints all the numbers instead of adding the 3 numbers.

The 3 numbers in the `txt` file are `95.0 90.0 80.0` on a single line. After input, they're displayed on 3 separate lines, which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
gradeTotal =gradeTotal+ myScanner.nextDouble();
//this adds the value from the file to the value in the variable
```

You were doing:

```
gradeTotal = myScanner.nextDouble();
//this just overwrites the value already in the variable.
```

Comment: @JavaCoder no I was not talking about you. Someone downvoted my answer and then upvoted it when I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
gradeTotal = myScanner.nextDouble();
```

with

```
gradeTotal += myScanner.nextDouble();
```

Then the average would be gradeTotal/i. Calculate the average outside the while loop. Only there the variables have reached the final value.

Comment: gradeTotal =gradeTotal+ myScanner.nextDouble();
//this adds the value from the file to the value in the variable                               That can't be the right answer as it is deprecated.                                                  gradeTotal += myScanner.nextDouble(); is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

place you sout out side the loop . And change this
gradeTotal = myScanner.nextDouble();
to
gradeTotal += myScanner.nextDouble();

```
public class AverageGrade {




        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException


    {       
            int i = 0;
            double sum = 0.0;
            double gradeTotal =  0.0;

            // Open the file

            File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\life__000\\Desktop\\Eclipse - Java\\AverageGrade\\src\\myGrades.txt");
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myFile);

            //Read lines from the file until no more are left.

            while (myScanner.hasNextDouble())

            {
                //Read the next name

                gradeTotal += myScanner.nextDouble();

                i++;

                //Display the last name read.




            }

            // Close the file.
  System.out.println(gradeTotal);
            myScanner.close();
        }

}
```